# Identification of a mammal in cage

Tags: species-identification, mammals

This unidentified animal was trapped in northern part of Kerala State India and images circulated through social media. Doea anyone know what species this is?

[image: The trapped animal]

[image]

Comment: Normal animals can look really strange if they lose all their hair. It looks like this one might have lost its hair due to disease. I don't know enough about what animals are native the area to make any suggestions.

Comment: Looks like a lemur to me, due to the long tail and finger-like front digits.

Comment: @C_Z_ Agreed. If you compare this image to that of a healthy lemur, you can see identical paws, teeth, ears, tail and hind legs.

Comment: On a net search Lemurs are seen only in Madagascar. The tail appears to be longer than the body. Can it be a Toddy cat (Palm Civet) with loss of hair?

Comment: @RamManoharM it can be a palm civet. [This](http://www.indiawilds.com/forums/showthread.php?7577-Asian-Palm-Civet) seems like a picture of another semi-hairless palm civet in Kerala.

Comment: @WYSIWYG  I didn't even think about the bio geography of it/ [This](http://cryptomundo.com/cryptozoo-news/yeti-civet/) looks like a fat version of the OP picture, so I think you're right.

Comment: Could be a civet.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like some kind of feline with mange.

It is unlikely to be a Lemur given the lack of thumbs on said animal. And this is India not Madagascar. Lemurs are only found on Madagascar.

Comment: This does not look like a lemur at all. This creature has whiskers... lemurs do not have whiskers.. More telling is the lack of tumbs. Lemurs have that... weird looking thumbs but thumbs. this animal does not. .https://www.google.com/search?q=lemur&biw=1252&bih=567&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwj0toOc7YjPAhUG4yYKHYFCDToQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=lemur+paws

Comment: Agreed, it's probably a cat, perhaps this https://www.google.com/search?q=Asian+Golden+Cat&sxsrf=ALeKk03eXvY-h6N7Ibq_GgdkzQej4BkQcA:1616468088878&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4kunxtMXvAhUQnxQKHfhkDuMQ_AUoAXoECA8QAw&biw=1267&bih=711#imgrc=4RDO6Zd8sVUI0M